# Is it possible to store an image with a value in a way similar to an array, in a database (Firebase or any other)?

Tags: python, database, firebase, pyrebase

Would it be possible to store an image and a value together in a database? Like in a array?
So it would be like [image, value]. I’m just trying to be able to access the image to print that and then access the value later (for example a image if a multi-choice question and its answer is the value).

Also how would I implement and access this? I’m using Firebase with the pyrebase wrapper for python but if another database is more suitable I’m open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you can set your computer as a server and in database you can store like [image_path, value].

Comment: How would I do this? I’m guessing I could store the image in the same folder as the program and with [image path, value] get the image that way, but how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For inserting image in database you have to convert the image to binary
Here is the code

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

def convertToBinaryData(filename):
    # Convert digital data to binary format
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        binaryData = file.read()
    return binaryData

def insertBLOB(emp_id, name, photo, biodataFile):
    print("Inserting BLOB into python_employee table")
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                             database='python_db',
                                             user='pynative',
                                             password='pynative@#29')

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('create table python_employee(id text, name text, photo BLOB, biodata text)
        sql_insert_blob_query = """ INSERT INTO python_employee
                          (id, name, photo, biodata) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"""

        empPicture = convertToBinaryData(photo)
        file = convertToBinaryData(biodataFile)

        # Convert data into tuple format
        insert_blob_tuple = (emp_id, name, empPicture, file)
        result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_blob_query, insert_blob_tuple)
        connection.commit()
        print("Image and file inserted successfully as a BLOB into python_employee table", result)

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed inserting BLOB data into MySQL table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if (connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

insertBLOB(1, "Eric", "D:\Python\Articles\my_SQL\images\eric_photo.png",
           "D:\Python\Articles\my_SQL\images\eric_bioData.txt")
insertBLOB(2, "Scott", "D:\Python\Articles\my_SQL\images\scott_photo.png",
           "D:\Python\Articles\my_SQL\images\scott_bioData.txt")
```

YO CAN also DO THIS BY `sqlite3` if mysql is not installed